# Polling endpoint with Angular 5 and merging received data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm quite new to Angular (I'm using the latest version cli) and sure there will be a very simple way to do what I'm trying (very badly to do), any help is appreciated!

We are rebuilding an application front end and at the moment our data is provided by the following endpoint /cars and we receive:

```
{
    "cars": ["Fiesta","Toyota", "Fiat"]
}
```

For each car, there is another endpoint with more details so `/Fiesta` returns:

```
{
    "Fiesta": [ ["model":"Sentra", "doors":4, "brand":"Fiesta"]
}
```

(these are simplified for the example)

I have a `car.service.ts` that makes the get request:

```
search(term: string) {
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}${term}`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
}
```

and then I get stuck... We use a polling system, so we do a get request to get the list of cars `this.search("cars")` and then for each car we do another get request for that specific cars details. This needs to run every 5-10 mins to stay updated when new cars are added or removed. This is what I've tried in `car.compontent.ts`:

```
doSearch(search: string) {
      this.service.search(search).subscribe((
        res => { this.cars = res; 
          for (let car of this.cars) {
            this.service.search(car).subscribe((
              result => { let newCar = {
                  show: true, car, result
                }; this.loaded.push(newCar);
              }))
          }})
      )};
```

And is displayed in the html like so;

```
<div *ngFor="let car of loaded">{{car.car}}
   <div *ngFor="let result of car.result">{{result.model}} {{result.doors}}<div>
</div>
```

Clearly this isn't right and horrible, as when I do a `setInterval` to run it every 5 mins the html just grows and repeats. If I empty the array in the `doSearch` first, I get what I want but the page flickers and rebuilds. All I'm trying to do is get the list of cars, and then for each car get a list of details for that car so can build a page shows the car header and details together, and that updates when the data is polled.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: This is not a technique I've used myself, but I found a recent post that may provide some assistance: https://nehalist.io/polling-in-angular/

Comment: When you do this.loaded.push(newCar); you are adding new items to the 'loaded' array. Is this what you need? Shouldn't you empty the array first, and also use the timer() from Observable? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html

Comment: Well if I empty the array first, the page literally goes blank for a second before the array is filled again - this is what I'm trying to avoid. I just want to update the array from the api calls and not be able to tell from the front end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly polling sucks. You should be using websockets / socket.io (server tells the client when data changes). However, I'm sure that would require server changes you don't have the time or inclination for. So on to your question ...

Basically in your service you create a method that returns an Observable that emits the exact values you want. So when you subscribe to it you are getting the data you want (or just use an async pipe instead of subsribing).

You service method would look something like this:

```
getCarDataIWant() {
    let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}${term}`;
    return this.http.get(apiURL)
      .pipe(
        tap((cars) => { console.log('cars', cars) }),
        mergeMap((cars) => { return this.http.get(apiURL + cars[0]) })
        tap((firstCar) => { console.log('firstCar', firstCar) }),
        // do your RxJS pipe transformations here
      );
  }
```

Inside the pipe section is where you transform the data. Each line inside the pipe transforms the data and passes the transformed data to the next line. I'm not going to spend time writing the entire thing for you but this is the basic approach you want. You will need to research which RxJS operators you will need. tap, map, mergeMap, switchMap are very popular. You will also need an operator to handle the iteration.

An RxJS observable is basically a stream. A stream is essentially an array over time as opposed to in memory. Therefore, most JavaScript array methods are valid RxJS operators.

A note on mergeMap. Most other operators are self-explanatory but this one is tricky. Basically this.http.get returns an Observable (AKA stream). But you don't want a stream on the next line, you want the value emitted from the stream, that's what mergeMap gives you.

Answer (score 0):

> If I empty the array in the doSearch first, I get what I want but the page flickers and rebuilds.

You can just reassign the array with the new data. To avoid flickering, you should use a `trackBy` function with your `ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let car of loaded; trackBy: trackByCar">{{car.car}}</div>
```

with something like

```
public trackByCar = (_, car) => car.id;
```